# Can we create only a Single object for a class

Tags: java, object, singleton

Is it possible to create only single object to the class?. How to do that in Java?

Comment: Expand your question please, for example, what language are you asking for?

Answer (score 8):

The following class definition is a *Singleton Pattern*:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The only way to retrieve an instance of the `Singleton` object for this class is to call the `getInstance()` method which insures that there will always be one instance of the `Singleton` object.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers suggest, the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) can guide your implementation so you create only a single instance of a class ... or not.

Truth is, many factors come into play, in particular if you're working under a managed environment, like an application server on top of a Java virtual machine. In that case, there can be multiple servers in a cluster, each server can start multiple JVMs, and each one can start multiple classloaders, each one of them creating a *different* instance of the "singleton" class. So, there is no way to guarantee that a single instance of an object will exist, for a given class!

Besides, many people thinks that [singletons are evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil), and you should consider carefully if you really need to use one, and whether your environment will allow it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use an enum

```
enum Singleton {
   INSTANCE;
}
```

The class is lazy loaded and thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

If you can provide details about language, It would be easy to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Usually creating only one object of a class smells of Singleton pattern.

Either you do not create any objects and use only class variables and methods or you use a proxy method.

Something like:

```
public static Object getInstance(){
  if(self.instance == null) {
    self.instance = new Object();
  }
  return self.instance;
}
```

Instead of calling new Object() in client side code you only call getIntstance();

Comment: I am sorry Let me rephrase the question If a class can only create one object. After creating one object it is not possible to create a Object. SO how can we do that ?

Comment: You will have to make the default constructor private. That way the only way to get at Object is through `getInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to implement the Singleton pattern, I recently came across an excellent article, [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx), which gives code examples and covers some potential issues.